# having space in the search key using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When i search using a space in the search key like "broad band" it didn't get any result, but gets the result when i only enter "broad".
the search should work with spaces also. my search query is like this.

```
    var searchedPhone = req.params.ani;

searchOnFieldWithOr = [{
        'field1': new RegExp(searchedPhone, 'i')
    }, {
        'field2': new RegExp(searchedPhone, 'i')
    }];


 contact.find({$or: searchOnFieldWithOr

    }).limit(20).skip(skip).exec(function (err, resp) {

      if (err) {

        res.send(err);
    }

    res.json(resp);
})
```

How to solve that problem please

Comment: What does your regex look like ?

Comment: this is the only regex, that i mentioned already,

Comment: What patterns are you matching ? what's `searchedPhone` ? is it only letters (\w) ? We need to see your regex.

Comment: searchedPhone is a string coming from the frontend, on which basis records are to be search, e.g searchedPhone = "Broad Band"